# Tutorial - Simulate a network: I've started 4 nodes (Alice/Bob/Charlie/Eve), but not all of the nodes show '3 peers'

Tags: peers, tutorials

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/simulate-network/

While working on this tutorial, I decided to go beyond the Alice and Bob nodes and also started Charlie and Eve nodes. While adding Charlie worked fine and all three nodes recognized 2 peers, adding Eve did not do the same. Alice and Bob correctly recognized 3 peers, but Charlie and Eve only recognized 2. I used the names from the previous tutorial when accessing localhost:8000 from 'yarn start'.

```
./target/release/node-template \    
--base-path /tmp/<name> \
--chain local \
--alice \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

What is the reason for this? It could very well be that my understanding of something if fundamentally wrong.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just setup Alice, Bob, Charlie, and Eve.

Here is a snippet of Eve's logs showing 3 peers connected:

```
2022-09-06 10:11:14  Idle (3 peers), best: #76 (0x714a…af6a), finalized #74 (0x0201…6fef), ⬇ 1.8kiB/s ⬆ 1.7kiB/s    
2022-09-06 10:11:18 ✨ Imported #77 (0xb648…03f7)    
2022-09-06 10:11:19  Idle (3 peers), best: #77 (0xb648…03f7), finalized #75 (0x9745…38bf), ⬇ 2.1kiB/s ⬆ 2.0kiB/s
```

Here is my setup:

**Alice**

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/alice \
--chain local \
--alice \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

**Bob**

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/bob \
--chain local \
--bob \
--port 30334 \
--ws-port 9946 \
--rpc-port 9934 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

**Charlie**

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/charlie \
--chain local \
--charlie \
--port 30335 \
--ws-port 9947 \
--rpc-port 9935 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

**Eve**

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/eve \
--chain local \
--eve \
--port 30336 \
--ws-port 9948 \
--rpc-port 9936 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

Version: `polkadot-v0.9.28`

Now keep in mind that by default, in the node-template, only Alice and Bob are authorities.